# How to update multiple rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Here is the Insert into select query which selects multiple rows from `GradePackages` table and inserts the data into `EmployeePackages` table:

```
insert into EmployeePackages (EmployeeId, GradeId, PackageId, Amount) 
    select 
        @EmployeeId,
        @GradeId,
        PackageId,
        Amount
    from 
        GradePackages   
    where 
        GradeId = @GradeId
```

Here `@EmployeeId` and `GradeId` have a single value each. But `PackageId` and `Amount`, each of them have 5 values.

The Insert query works fine, but the problem is with the update query. I need to update i.e. copy rows from the `GradePackages` table (where I input a specific `GradeId`) into the `EmployeePackages` table (where specific `EmployeeId` is input). I know it will work on a single row but there are multiple rows and that is the problem. I have tried different types of Update queries but it doesn't work. Have a look please. Thank you.

`EmployeePackages` table:

| Id | EmployeeId | GradeId | PackageId | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1036 | 30 | 1 | 29980.00 |
| 14 | 1036 | 30 | 2 | 5000.00 |
| 15 | 1036 | 30 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 16 | 1036 | 30 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 17 | 1036 | 30 | 5 | 0.00 |
| 18 | 1037 | 31 | 1 | 34000.00 |
| 19 | 1037 | 31 | 2 | 6000.00 |
| 20 | 1037 | 31 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 21 | 1037 | 31 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 22 | 1037 | 31 | 5 | 0.00 |

`GradePackages` table:

| Id | GradeId | PackageId | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 30 | 1 | 34650.00 |
| 12 | 30 | 2 | 5000.00 |
| 13 | 30 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 14 | 30 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 15 | 30 | 5 | 0.00 |
| 16 | 29 | 1 | 41090.00 |
| 17 | 29 | 2 | 6000.00 |
| 18 | 29 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 19 | 29 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 20 | 29 | 5 | 0.00 |

Output needed (`EmployeePackages`):

| Id | EmployeeId | GradeId | PackageId | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1036 | 29 | 1 | 41090.00 |
| 14 | 1036 | 29 | 2 | 6000.00 |
| 15 | 1036 | 29 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 16 | 1036 | 29 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 17 | 1036 | 29 | 5 | 0.00 |
| 18 | 1037 | 31 | 1 | 34000.00 |
| 19 | 1037 | 31 | 2 | 6000.00 |
| 20 | 1037 | 31 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 21 | 1037 | 31 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 22 | 1037 | 31 | 5 | 0.00 |

Expected results:

Let's say I `select` rows with `GradeId = 29` (5 rows) from `GradePackages` and `update EmployeePackages where EmployeeId = 1036`

Comment: *Consumable* sample data and expected results, along with your attempt(s) will help us help you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) This is why I asked for *consumable* data.

Comment: I have removed images and added data. Thankyou

Comment: Can you provide the table output you need?

Comment: I don't understand the logic. For example how does `29980.00` and `34650.00` become `41090.00`

Comment: only 29980.00 change into 41090. First I select EmployeeId from EmployeePackages which needs update (5 rows will be updated). Let's take EmployeeId=1036 to update. Then I select which Grade (from GradePackages) will be selected for update purpose. Let's take GradeId=29 (5 rows). So new grade will be updated in EmployeePackages table. From the above, we can say that **Id** 16,17,18,19,20 (from GradePackages) will  replace **Id** 13,14,15,16,17 (in EmployeePackages). Hope it clarifies. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you said Update; not insert so...

```
DECLARE @GradeID AS Numeric(4,0)=29
DECLARE @EmployeeID as Numeric(4,0)=1036

UPDATE EmployeePackages 
SET EmployeePackages.Amount = GP.Amount,
    EmployeePackages.GradeID = @GradeID  --added this and , above.
FROM EmployeePackages EP
INNER JOIN GradePackages GP
  ON EP.PackageID = GP.PackageID
WHERE EP.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
  AND GP.GradeID = @GradeID
```

Consider:

- [Parameterizing SQL UPDATE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377927/parameterizing-sql-update-query)
- [SQL Update from One Table to Another Based on a ID Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

[Example Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb971a7dd5cf9b6282a958aca1aeae8e)  Special thanks to RF1991 so I didn't have to re-create the fiddle.

Resulting in:

```
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
|   Id    | EmployeeId | GradeId | PackageId |  Amount  |
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
| 13      |       1036 |      29 |         1 | 41090.00 |
| 14      |       1036 |      29 |         2 |  6000.00 |
| 15      |       1036 |      29 |         3 |     0.00 |
| 16      |       1036 |      29 |         4 |     0.00 |
| 17      |       1036 |      29 |         5 |     0.00 |
| 18      |       1037 |      31 |         1 | 34000.00 |
| 19      |       1037 |      31 |         2 |  6000.00 |
| 20      |       1037 |      31 |         3 |     0.00 |
| 21      |       1037 |      31 |         4 |     0.00 |
| 22      |       1037 |      31 |         5 |     0.00 |
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thankyou. But it copies only the first row from the first table and pastes that first row into 5 rows into the 2nd table. What is needed is that 5 different rows copied from one table and pasted into another table.

Comment: Odd... the join on EP and GP package Id should prevent that.  I'll have to take a look. I would have thought the join and where clause would have prevented that issue.

Comment: @MWaqarAnwar I'm not able to recreate your issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=464f49ab07c92228bedf2d1f23055635  Special thanks to RF1991 as I stole their example and used my update on it.  So I'd have to say it's in your implementation unless I don't understand the question.

Comment: I did have to make 1 update to also set the gradeID which I missed initially

Answer (score 0):

for update using `Subquery`

```
UPDATE employeepackages
SET    employeepackages.gradeid = t.gradeid,
       employeepackages.amount = t.amount
FROM   (SELECT GP.gradeid,
               GP.packageid,
               GP.amount
        FROM   gradepackages GP
               FULL JOIN employeepackages EP
                      ON EP.gradeid = GP.gradeid
                         AND EP.packageid = GP.packageid
        WHERE  EP.gradeid IS NULL) t
WHERE  employeeid = @EmployeeId
       AND employeepackages.gradeid = @GradeId
       AND employeepackages.packageid = t.packageid
```

[subquery fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=128e887c3f0a72c01999c0b6bf4c7b13)

or with `CTE`

```
;with t as(
SELECT 
       GP.gradeid ,
       GP.packageid ,
       GP.amount 
       FROM   gradepackages GP
       FULL JOIN employeepackages EP
              ON EP.gradeid = GP.gradeid
                 AND EP.packageid = GP.packageid
WHERE  EP.gradeid IS NULL  )

UPDATE e
SET    e.gradeid = t.gradeid,
       e.amount = t.amount
FROM   employeepackages e
       JOIN t
         ON e.packageid = t.packageid
WHERE  e.employeeid = @EmployeeId
       AND e.GradeId = @GradeId
```

[cte fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8f7382970ea83bbb1d8ad78c6b56ff6)

Comment: EmployeeId is Id from Employees Table. where as Id is of GradePackages Table. Similar is the case for EmployeePackages Table.

Comment: I have changed my answer that fits to your problem.

Comment: I have added the fiddle go to link